# CakePHP - Tree Behaviour: multidimensional associative array to tree

Tags: cakephp, tree, cakephp-3.0, saving-data

I am just getting started with the CakePHP 3 Tree behaviour (https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/behaviors/tree.html). I have a situation where I have an existing tree and I would like to reorder them based on an array. I tried it like this:

```
        $data = [
            [
                'id' => 1,
                'parent_id' => null,
                'children' => [
                    [
                        'id' => 3,
                        'children' => [
                            'id' => 4,
                            'children' => [
                                'id' => 5
                            ]
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            ],
            [
                'id' => 2,
                'parent_id' => false
            ],
        ];

        $minutesTable->patchEntities($minutes, $data);

        $minutesTable->saveMany($minutes);
```

...Hoping that the `children` field would work, but unfortunately no. The attempt above doesn't return an error, but the `children` field is simply ignored.

Is there a built-in way to achieve this? What would an elegant alternative be?

Just to add: changing an individual `parent_id` works in my application. What I am looking for is completely restructuring the tree using a reference array.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve by using a reference array? There is no such built-in functionality, you'd have to figure something on your own. Given how updating nested sets works, doing multiple moves/saves/deletes is probably inevitable.

Comment: I want to save the state of a JQuery nested sortable list. I figured to easiest way was to convert the nested list into an array and go from there. But if that's not possible I could instead use individual operations.

Answer (score -1):

I think you should find out association in cakephp. 
Link : [Cakephp 3 Association](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/associations.html)

For example You have one parent and many children, and children have many children. 
So, Parent will become the mean data. And those table must have relationship between each other. 
I will override your array as the Example:

```
$data = array:2 [
   0 => array:2 [
      "parent_id" => "1"
      "name" => "Mr. A"
      "childrens" => array:2 [
          0 => array:2 [
            "id" => "32"
            "parent_id" => "1"
            "name" => "Mr. A SON"
            "grand_childrens" => array:1 [
                0 => array:0 [
                "id" => "4"
                "grand_children_id" => "32"
                "name" => "Mr. A GRAND SON"
                ]
            ]
          ],
          1 => array:0 [
            "id" => "2"
            "parent_id" => "1"
            "name" => "Mr. A Daughter"
          ]
      ]

    ],
    1 => array:2 [
      "parent_id" => "2"
      "name" => "Mr. B"
      "childrens" => array:2 [
          0 => array:2 [
            "id" => "5"
            "parent_id" => "2"
            "name" => "Mr. B SON"
            "grand_childrens" => array:1 [
                0 => array:0 [
                "id" => "7"
                "grand_children_id" => "5"
                "name" => "Mr. B GRAND SON"
                ]
            ]
          ],
          1 => array:0 [
            "id" => "4"
            "parent_id" => "2"
            "name" => "Mr. B Daughter"
          ]
      ]

    ]

]
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. You talk about associations but that's between different models. The question addresses a tree, which is within a single model.

Comment: @Roberto I try to explain the to them I think he provide the wrong associate structure. This example may be help key for them.